# How do I transfer filles from my Mac to my PC using a LAN cable?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, mac, file-transfer

I've been looking up this question online, but I can't seem to find a good walkthrough.

I have a Mac OS X 10.6.9 Snow Leopard (laptop), and I want to transfer a few gigs of stuff to my Windows 7 PC (desktop). I have a LAN cable which I'd prefer to use in transferring these files.

I'd love some input on how to do this from anyone who's done this before.

Comment: Is it a **crossed** LAN cable? (It should say so on the cable itself)

Comment: I don't know, it's a typical cat5 cable. The type that hooks a computer to another computer, or a computer to a router.

Comment: @slhck: aren't most NICs [auto-MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_dependent_interface#Auto-MDIX)  nowadays?

Comment: @Red Duh. Of course. It's been a while since my last real networking experience :)

Answer (score 1):

I've only done this between a Windows and a Linux machine via a regular twisted-pair ethernet cable. What I did was assign a static IP to each (like 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2), same subnet and set the gateway to the opposite counterparts (1.1.1.1 gw -> 1.1.1.2, etc). For that you would need to edit the *properties* of a corresponding device in **ncpa.cpl** (start -> run) and the *interfaces* file on OSX. You would need some service to be deployed in order to actually transfer the files. I used the Windows implementation of the **SMB** protocol (File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks), hence Windows acting as the serving host (thus no need for Client for Microsoft Networks). Then I just mounted the Windows share as **CIFS** on my *client* host and that's that.

Oh, yeah, **firewall.cpl** might need some adjustments. For testing purposes, **ping** might be desirable as well for connectivity testing between your hosts.

Comment: If you start up a network with two client PCs (and no static config and no DHCP service) don't they assign themselves zero-config addresses in the range 169.254.xxx.xxx. Do you need a gateway configured if all traffic is to/from computers in the same LAN (i.e. same subnet)?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: yes, you are definitely right about that :) I mainly used the preconfigured IPs for their simplicity (1.1.x.x vs 169.254.x.x) - basically, just to input less when manually accessing the share :P (browsing excluded). But that actually makes me do more, count to think of it.. Guess I just never trusted the zero-configuration :-) Time to change my mind. And about the gateway, well, I think that might just be my misconception - was always under the impression that Windows` network properties box would not close unless the gw was there. I'll take that into account now, thanks!